# Argument Not Optional and Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment Errors

Tags: vba, excel

I would like the following code to run each time the workbook opens.  I am getting a couple of errors that you can see in my comments.  I'm pretty sure it is a very simple thing that I am missing and I have not been able to figure it out.  Thank you for your time!

```
Public FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Public SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Public FileItem As Scripting.File
Public FolderName As Object

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'I would like to run this every time the workbook opens. This is where I am getting my Argument Not Optional Error.
Call ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder)

End Sub

Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, Subfolders As Boolean) 'Do I need everything in the parentheses?

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MsgBox "SOP's Database will update automatically"

Dim r, LstR As Long
Dim SOPRng As Range

Set SOPRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SOPDatabase").Range

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SOPDatabase").Unlist

SOPRng.ClearFormats

UserName = Environ("UserName")
fPath = "Target File Path"

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(fPath)

    r = 2

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files

        Cells(r, 1) = r - 1
        Cells(r, 2) = FileItem.Name
        Cells(r, 3) = FileItem.Type
        Cells(r, 4) = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"

        r = r + 1

    Next FileItem
I can get up to here to work just fine.  Going into the subfolders below is not working.  I am getting  error.

    If Subfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True '"wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" and "ListFilesInFolder" is highlighted
        Next SubFolder
    End If
'The rest of the macro is working just fine.

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

LstR = ActiveSheet.Columns("$B").End(xlDown).Row

Set SOPRng = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$" & LstR)

Set SOPDatabase = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, SOPRng, , xlYes, , "TableStyleMedium2")

        SOPDatabase.Name = "SOPDatabase"

With SOPDatabase.Range
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
With SOPDatabase.HeaderRowRange
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 14
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
    .WrapText = True
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It may be my lack of knowledge of VBA and how to define variables.  I am still trying to understand that part.

Comment: Are you trying to call the sub within itself?

Comment: @Brotato- it's optionally recursive. That's what the `Subfolders` parameter is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the code you posted will compile. You call `Call ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder)`, but the sub requires two arguments: SourceFolder and Subfolders. Did you perhaps add the `Subfolders` parameter to `ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, Subfolders As Boolean)` AFTER you got the "wrong number of arguments" error in `ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True`?

In other words, does this code currently compile and run up until `ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True`?

Comment: @ Ken-Yes, the code runs up until ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True.  That is exactly where I am getting the error and I do not understand why.  Is there a simple fix?

Comment: Are you still having a problem with this? Basically, the problem is not with the `ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True` function call itself, but rather the `ListObjects("SOPDatabase")`, which no longer exists on the second time through the function. It was unlisted the first time through the function. You may not be seeing the error in the proper place due to a setting. In the VB Editor go to "Tools">"Options">"General">"Error Trapping">"Break in Class Module". Move the recursive section to its own function, and I suggest moving the `ListFilesInFolder` function to its own module. Easier testing.

Comment: I have actually figured it out.  I had to define some variables prior to running the Call and it worked perfectly.  The problem was those variables were being set every time it ran through the beginning of the ListFilesInFolder and they needed to be set permanently before going into the sub.  Thank you for your help Ken!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Call ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder)
```

to

```
Call ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder,True)
```

this should at least yield a different error from your current one

Comment: No. Just no. That wouldn't even compile. Parens are **never** needed when calling a `Sub` procedure.

Comment: well, tell them that! https://www.homeandlearn.org/passing_values_to_a_sub.html 
I remember parenthesis being annoying in VBA, so I'll give you the benefit of my doubt :)

Comment: Notice the explicit `Call` statement, missing here (and obsolete BTW). The code you posted would not compile, it attempts to evaluate `(SubFolder, True)` as an expression and pass the result `ByVal` to the procedure. It's wrong. In any case, `DoStuff foo, bar` and `Call DoStuff (foo, bar)` are *exactly the same thing*, so that's 4 quarters for a dollar.

Comment: Sorry, got interrupted.. well you got it, I'll discard my draft.. +1

Comment: thanks for the insights though, hopefully this time the proper syntax will stick in my brain :)